# NestJS Sequelize - fields, which can be null are not recognized as possible null in rest of code

Tags: typescript, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I am starting to work with NestJS and PostgreSQL databases.
I created a model called `User`. In this model is a column named `verifiedAt`.
It looks like:

```
@Column({
    type: DataType.DATE,
    allowNull: true,
})
verifiedAt: Date | null;
```

A value of the column can be null. But when I reference this property from another place in my code, the IDE doesn't recognize that it may be null. Shows only the `Date` type.

[image: Type]

Why it is like this? What should I change to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a resolution. In tsconfig.json the `strictNullChecks` flag must be set to `true`.